# "Item not found in this collection" error when I try to insert

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In an event of a Form I write some code to select value from a table and insert it into another table. This is my code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT std_crs_absence.std_name, std_crs_absence.stg_number, std_crs_absence.crs_name, Sum(std_crs_absence.absence_time) AS SumOfabsence_time, Sum(std_crs_absence.molat) AS SumOfmolat " & _
"FROM std_crs_absence GROUP BY std_crs_absence.std_name, std_crs_absence.stg_number, std_crs_absence.crs_name ", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO abs_summary ([std_name],[stg_number],[crs_name],[SumOfabsence_time],[SumOfmolat])" & _
    " VALUES ('" & rs("std_name") & "','" & rs("stg_number") & "','" & rs("crs_name") & "'," & rs("absence_time") & "," & rs("molat") & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlinsert)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

When the event is executed it gives me an error that says "Item not found in this collection". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you first SELECT the data you retrieve the sums as `SumOfabsence_time` and `SumOfmolat`, but for the INSERT you try to use `rs("absence_time")` and `rs("molat")`. Those columns don't exist in the Recordset so you get the error. You'll need to use `rs("SumOfabsence_time")` and `rs("SumOfmolat")` instead.

*(Obligatory comment: You really should be using a parameterized query instead of dynamic SQL.)*

Comment: thank you, i try do that but it gives me the same error, the problem is not in that point